# Problems in Haskell's Type-System

Tags: haskell

Ive come across some answers (here in SO) saying that Haskell has many "dark corners" in its type system, and also some messy holes. Could someone elaborate on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Care to post links to those answers?

Comment: well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770774/what-language-to-learn-after-haskell, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822752/should-i-learn-haskell-or-f-if-i-already-know-ocaml/823338#823338

Comment: I guess the need for `zip2, zip3, zip4` etc is somewhat problematic ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess I should answer this, especially since two people so far have misinterpreted my remarks...

Regarding non-termination, the remark in question was slight hyperbole for dramatic effect, and referred to non-termination at the *value* level. This was in context of comparing Haskell to *theorem provers*, in an answer to someone who mentioned type-enforced correctness properties as something they particularly appreciated. In that sense, the presence of ⊥ inhabiting otherwise empty types is a "flaw", because it changes the meaning of a type like `A -> B` from "given an A, produces a B" into "given an A, either produces a B or crashes the program" which is, for obvious reasons, somewhat less satisfying from a proof-of-correctness standpoint.

It's also completely irrelevant to almost all day-to-day programming and no worse than any other general-purpose language because, of course, the possibility of non-termination is required for Turing-completeness.

I don't have any problem with `UndecidableInstances`. Actually, it bothers me less than ⊥ at the value level does because it only crashes GHC when compiling, not the finished program. `OverlappingInstances` is another matter, though, and the ad hoc mishmash of GHC extensions to provide little bits of things that would most naturally require dependent types certainly qualifies as "messy".

But keep in mind that most of the things I'm complaining about in Haskell are only a problem because of the otherwise very solid foundation. Most type systems in other statically typed languages aren't even coherent enough to be called "wrong" in comparison, and cleaning up the stuff I'm calling "messy" is an active and ongoing area of research.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was surprised at what I thought you were arguing, but I didn't go and carefully try to read the quoted phrase in context.

Comment: On a nitpicking level, I'd distinguish between, by the way, "crashes the program" and nontermination, by the way. Remember our slogan -- well typed programs don't go wrong!

Comment: @sclv: In practice, yes, absolutely. In the context of type-enforced correctness, distinguishing between different kinds of ⊥ is rearranging deck chairs on the Titanic. I probably should have said something like "... or evaluates to ⊥" instead, but... poetic license, I guess?

Answer (score 6):

Haskell's type system has no problems or messy holes, actually. Haskell 98 can be fully type-inferred. It possesses what is known as the "principal type" property, which is to say that any given expression has at most a single most general type. There are, however, a range of expressions which are good and useful and valid but do not type under Haskell 98. Most important of these are higher-ranked types. `forall a b. (a -> b) -> a -> b` is an (uninteresting) example of a rank-one type, which is to say that the `forall` is only at the very outside. `forall b. -> (forall a. a -> a) -> b -> b` is an example of a useless but possible type which is not rank-one, and cannot be expressed in Haskell98. Higher ranked types are one of many things which break the principal type property.

As one adds more and more extensions to the basic Haskell98 system, there begin to be tradeoffs introduced between the ability to write really powerful types which express both different types of polymorphism and different types of constraints and the ability to have as much code as possible completely type-inferred. At the very edges of what's possible, types can get messy and complicated, and occasionally you can run into things that seem like they should work but don't. But at that point, you're generally doing what's known as "type-level programming" where a great deal of your application logic has been embedded in the types themselves, and through a combination of typeclass tricks you've conned the compiler into, essentially, running the types as a program at compile time.

I disagree, by the way, with camccann's assertion that potential nontermination is a messy compromise in the type-checker. I think it's a perfectly useful feature, in fact a prerequisite for turning-completeness at the type level, and you only risk it if you explicitly ask the compiler to start allowing lots of dodgy stuff.

Comment: Speaking of nitpicking--not exactly relevant to the question, but it looks really really weird when people capitalize my username like that, since it's my first initial ++ middle initial ++ last name. I should probably change my display name here to something more sensible [like I use elsewhere](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/user/7309).

Comment: @camccann -- capitalization fixed :-)

Comment: I don't think it's worth adding a whole new answer just for this, but perhaps you could also mention the monomorphism restriction? I find this to be a rather ugly complication of the type system which tends to bite a lot of beginners.

Comment: @pelotom -- I agree and disagree. The MR is a bit of a wart, but it isn't intrinsic to the type system (gone from Haskell 2010) and once you overcome the initial confusion, doesn't tend to cause much pain. So, like defaulting, it complicates things a bit, but in what I'd consider an irritating but trivial way rather than a deep one.

Comment: @sclv what do you mean by "gone from Haskell 2010"? The Haskell 2010 report still mentions it: http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-880004.5. And why is it not intrinsic to the type system? It's certainly intrinsic to how type inferencing works.

Comment: @pelotom -- you're right, its still in Haskell 2010, but the proposal should still be on track for a Haskell revision real soon now. It is not intrinsic to the type system because it is trivial to turn off -- its just an extra rule stuck on top of type inferencing. if you write something that violates it, you get an error -- it doesn't change the type of well-typed expressions.

Comment: @sclv when interacting with defaulting rules it indirectly does change the type of well-typed expressions in unexpected ways: `let p = print`, `let (f, g) = ((+), (-))`

Answer (score 1):

So you're referring to Camccann saying "Haskell's type system is full of holes, due to nontermination and other messy compromises"?  I think he's talking about the [UndecidableInstances](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0-latest/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#undecidable-instances) extension and probably a few others.

Then you referred to Norman, I can only assume, saying "Haskell's type system is ambitious and powerful, but it is continually being improved, which means there is some inconsistency as a result of history.".  I'm sure he had something in mind but will let him clarify when he see`s this question.

Comment: I suspect that Norman Ramsey was talking about the not-entirely-understood interaction between various experimental GHC extensions, particularly things like GADTs, overlapping instances, type families, and whatnot--stuff I've seen someone (McBride, perhaps?) refer to as a "ghastly hodgepodge".